# MATLAB help Using indexing

Tags: matlab

I need to Build a MATLAB script that makes the top left window of size 50x50 and the bottom right window of size 50x50 of the image completely white.The image is cameraman.tiff. I am completely stumped cause I need to use indexing.

Comment: What do you mean `I need to use indexing`? And be more specific: you want to modify an image or a gui?

Comment: I need to modify the image with MATLAB. I am new to MATLAB and I am having problems with simply starting. I put the image in a matrix A to start with and somehow I need to replace all the top left 50x50 of the image with white and the bottom right 50x50 with white as well. Since its in a matrix I am assuming I can replace these values in those sections with white

Comment: The image is cameraman.tif

Comment: Can you add the code for reading the image? Did you use `imread`?

Comment: Yes sir, I did place the image into A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straightforward solution:

```
im  = imread('cameraman.tif');
mS  = 50;
imN = im;
imN(1:mS, 1:mS) = uint8(255);
imN(end-mS+1:end, end-mS+1:end) = uint8(255);    
imshow(imN)
```

[image]

---

**Edit:**

Don't overrate indexing, it is not hard. You can do anything you want using correct indexing. This is another case:

```
im  = imread('cameraman.tif');
mS  = 50;
imN = im;
imN(1:mS, end-mS+1:end) = uint8(255);
imN(end-mS+1:end, 1:mS) = uint8(255);    
imshow(imN)
```

[image]

Comment: I believe that's what I am looking for. What if you want to replace the right half of the image with the left side and vice versa. So this coding, for a person like me, seems complicated.

Comment: @RLJ - Is it clear after editing, or you want me to explain the code step by step or which part exactly seems to you comlicated?

Answer (score 0):

The thing you area asking is trivial. Your statement about indexing (whatever that meant is also misleading).

Anyway in matlab since you have the image as matrix you can assign values to the various pixels just as with any other matrix.

For example if you have double values in RGB color space `0` signifies black and `1` signifies white. So, just assign these values to the corresponding pixels. If there is something else, post your code and the specific problem. Also you can do a google search before asking

Comment: I did and I guess I don't know exactly how to ask. I am sorry if I appear to not know what I am talking about. To be honest I am learning and really don't understand how to even begin. This is what I have and don't k ow how to use the 0 and 1 your talking about.

Comment: Now I am somehow going to edit the top left 50x50 and bottom right 50x50 with white. I believe im supposed to make another variable. Say B = (this 50x50 all white in the first rows and columns of the 50x50) and merge it with the image to white it out

Comment: I would suggest to read about working with matrices in matlab. There is no point in asking every little thing you come up with. How to assign, to invert, to select sub-matrices etc, fundamental stuff

Comment: Im in a class. Professor covered it and I have googled it and something just isn't clicking. I will say this though. I am interested in learning this and that's why I am here. This is a free place to ask questions and those that take the time to help are much appreciated. You don't have to bash me for asking questions.

Comment: I am not bashing you. You are free to ask whatever you want but be warned that people in SO (not nessecerily including me) are often downvoting for not sticking with the general rules. Good luck